# Should we start a 'repeat-visits' tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are tons of questions with people asking how often they can visit Country X:

[Can I leave South Africa before my 90 days expire, and return after a few days to stay for another 90 days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45156/can-i-leave-south-africa-after-90-day-limit-and-return-after-a-few-days-with-ne)

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60567/if-i-re-enter-south-africa-from-my-home-country-will-i-get-another-90-days?lq=1

[UK Visitor Visa: Required Time or Interval Between Visits?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43767/uk-visitor-visa-required-time-or-interval-between-visits)

[How soon can I re-enter the USA having stayed for 90 days under the Visa Waiver Program?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13964/how-soon-can-i-re-enter-the-usa-having-stayed-for-90-days-under-the-visa-waiver)

[Time between visits without a visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24732/time-between-visits-without-a-visa)

I'm thinking we could get a ***repeat-visits*** tag so that it's easy to find one of those questions for each country. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Th tag exists and is presently applied to 16 questions that are Open.