# Merging [repeat-visits] with [visa-runs]

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've originally [proposed](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3554/should-we-start-a-repeat-visits-tag) starting a [repeat-visits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeat-visits) tag, which was accepted, but I've since noticed that we also have a very similar [visa-runs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-runs) tag.

Perhaps we could merge the two into a single [repeat-visits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeat-visits) tag?

Comment: They're quite different, no? Repeat visits can be going in an out of a country on say, business, while visa run is usually jumping outside to renew a visa, then returning in?

Comment: @MarkMayo most questions are kind-of borderline, so I'm not sure if we need the distinction.

Comment: Eg I've done repeat-visits in my past, but I've never done a visa run. I'd personally keep them separate, but it's just a view, so remains a comment for now.

Comment: Repeat visits can also apply when you don't need a visum at all. I can e.g. imagine someone asking if there are better alternatives than buying separate 'Z' tickets when repeatedly visiting 'X'.

Comment: People ask questions about back-to-back visa applications and back-to-back visits. I like @MarkMayo's advice in this case.  Perhaps elaboration on the tag definitions to emphasize the difference and refer to each other could be useful.

Comment: Another potential confusion is with *[tag:multiple-entry]*, which I had assumed was for multiple-entry visas, but instead says it is for "Questions regarding possibilities of Multiple Entry into the country."

Answer (score 4):

The Usage guides are:

[visa-run](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-run): Leaving a country for a short time in order to renew your visa or obtain a new one.

[repeat-visits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeat-visits):For questions about repeatedly visiting a given country in a short period of time. E.g. visiting the UK three times in a row on back-to-back tourist visas.

The concepts are different (for the former the sole purpose of travel is to 'requalify', for the latter it could just as easily be the need to be somewhere else between visits or any one of very many other reasons).

In any case, visa runs seem by definition on topic at [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions about work, residence, student, investor and similar mid and long term visas aimed for staying in the country for more time than a tourist or short term business visa would allow

while raises doubt as to whether on topic for Travel (though I am well aware some questions may be on topic at more than a single SE site).

Merging the two would not be a good idea.